# WP_Query compare with dynamic values

Tags: wp-query

I need get a post only if publish_date is equal to modified date in this case the post is not modified! So i need post NOT MODIFIED!:

My query is:

```
 $lastupdated_args = array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'date_query' => [
        [ 'before' => 'post_modified' ]
    ],
        'date_query' => [
        [ 
            'column'    => 'post_modified_gmt', 
            'after'     => 'post_date_gmt', 
            'inclusive' => false 
        ]
    ],

    ); 

    function wpse_modified( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
        // Run only once:
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        // Append custom SQL
        return $where . " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified} != {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified} ";
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_modified' );

    $lastupdated_loop = new WP_Query( $lastupdated_args );
    query_posts( $lastupdated_args );
```

How to get a dynamic value like date (published and modified) during this query for comparison?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get only modified posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208307/get-only-modified-posts)

Comment: I need get post not modified, not only modified, next time read the question please... no duplicate...

Comment: Which has the same answer with an extremely simple change from the solution to the other question. Just change `!=` (not equals) to `=`.

Comment: The query is different... AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified} != {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified}, post_modified != post_modified?? really?? a =! a?? How to implement in my qp_query??

Comment: You *can't* do it in WP_Query. Which is covered in the question I marked as duplicate.

Comment: I have updated with the code but nothing work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79838/discussion-between-marcus-j-kennedy-and-jacob-peattie).